# how to use onResume activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to build an application in which I am applying password on application. when the user left the application and open again then I will ask for the password. for example application is running , the user clicks the home button means left the application then he open it again the the application will ask for the password.

I am creating a password dialog in `onResume()` method of activity. but the problem is that if the user goes to the next screen and comes back to that screen then also `onResume()` will execute and will ask for the password. but I don't want this. I want password alert should occur only if he left the application and come again. please tell me any solution where should I write that code.

Comment: I predict that it will be somewhat difficult for you to pull this off.  You are trying to impose some notion of application lifecycle that Android doesn't recognize or support.  The "home" button doesn't cause you to "leave" an application.  Your first step will be to be clear about what it means to "leave" the application, in Android terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try.

Suppose u have A,B activity,  create a static variable in A as loggedIn=false;

now suppose u started B from A, on B onbackpress method always make loggedIn=true;

In activity A's on resume method check

if(!loggedIn){
showLogin dialog
}
then assign true again
loggedIn=true;

now if user press home button loggedIn flag will be false and when resumes application the login dialog will be called.

Comment: use of static variables is not recommended. It may lead to memory leaks.

Comment: can u please tell me how i will make it true on onBackpress?

Comment: In activity A  write public static boolean loggedIn=false; no  activity B @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 A.loggedIn=true;
 super.onBackPressed();
} let me know if it works

Comment: hey still problem. i am doing the same now. but suppose i am going to B and then coming back to A then loggedin will be true and then i am closing the application and coming again it will be true again.

Comment: now i got the solution. what you told is right but we also need to set loggedin=false in onStop().

Comment: Yes Sachin you can use this method in every activity onPause method make it loggedin=false, and in on resume make it always true, do this on every activity. I just tested it, its working as u wanted.

Comment: Static variables lead to memory leaks?  Where do people come up with this stuff?

Comment: I second that ;-) Although I have to admit that there are certain posts by Google people that tell you that putting SOME things in static variables may cause memory leaks (like keeping a ref to a Context)? In the end it is just business as usual: know what your store and when to delete it..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two activities a(displaying dialog) and b.When you navigate from one activity a to another activity b. Activity a goes to background. activity b is in foreground. both are put to activity backstack. back stack works like LIFO (Last in first out). When you click back button. activity b is pushed from back stack  and activity a is displayed. When activity is paused it has to resume. When you activity is stopped onStart() is called and in succesion onResume() is called. So if you calling dialog in onResume() it iwll get displayed.

Have look at the below links.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.

**Note Quoted from the above link:** Multiple tasks can be held in the background at once. However, if the user is running many background tasks at the same time, the system might begin destroying background activities in order to recover memory, causing the activity states to be lost. See the following section about Activity state.

Edit

You must implement the onCreate() method to perform basic application startup logic that should happen only once for the entire life of the activity. So display dialog in onCreate() not onResume(). Unless activity is destroyed it is not created again.

Comment: i know all this. i am asking for any solution how can i do what i want to do.

Comment: tell me any thing which will execute only when the user come back to the application.

Comment: onCreate will also execute in both the situations.

Comment: means onCreate will execute in both the situation when we restart the application or we came back from any other activity.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html. Have a look at headin Create a New Instance 2nd paragraph. I suggest you have a read of the above two links.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an activity to handle the Authentication process and lets call it (A).
and let your current activities be (B) and (C).
So, this is how it goes:

1- activity (A) is the launcher.

2- add `android:noHistory="true"` to the `<activity>` tag of activity (A) in the manifest.xml

3- from (A) you can navigate to  (B) then to (C).

4- from (C) you can navigate back to (B) but you'll not be able to navigate back to (A).

Answer (score 0):

You can set variable when home key is pressed

```
@Override

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

   if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
     fromHome = true;
    }

return false;
};
```

and set variable false when you navigating from this activity

```
fromHome = false;
```

and check flag in `OnResume()`

Comment: hey this works only in old versions of android i.e in android GB not is android ICS and Jelly Bean

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that what you are actually trying to keep track of is number of "Started" Activities in your Application: #(Started activities) > 0 would then mean that your application hasn't been put to the background, because if the user presses Home, ALL your App's Activities are bound to have onStop() called.

In order to keep track of the number of "Started" Activities you could introduce a singleton like so:

```
public class LifecycleTracker {

private LifecycleTracker mInstance;

private int mNrOfStarted;

private LifecycleTracker() {
    mNrOfStarted = 0;
}

public static LifecycleTracker getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new LifecycleTracker();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public void incrementStarted() {
    mNrOfStarted++;
}

public void decrementStarted() {
    mNrOfStarted--;
}

public boolean fromBackground() {
    return mNrOfStarted == 0;
}
}
```

Then, in all your Activity's onStart() methods you should first check if you are coming from the background:

```
if (LifecycleTracker.getInstance().fromBackground()) {
    //start authentication
    //don't forget to increment after authentication as well!
} else {
    LifecycleTracker.getInstance().incrementStarted();
}
```

And in all your Activity's onStop() methods you should decrement:

LifecycleTracker.getInstance().decrementStarted();